# Solving a congruence equation

Tags: number-theory

Let $\pi$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity, $p$ some prime and
$$ x= \sqrt{ \left(\frac{ \pi^k -1}{\pi-1}\right) \overline{\left(\frac{ \pi^k -1}{\pi-1}\right)} } \in \mathbb{Z}[\pi]$$
for some natural exponent $k<p$. Is it really true that $x \equiv k \operatorname {mod} (\pi-1)$ ?

Thanks for helping

---

edit: to use a different notation, let $\pi:=\vartheta$

Comment: Using $\pi$ here is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas\hints :

$$\left(\frac{ \pi^k -1}{\pi-1}\right) \overline{\left(\frac{ \pi^k -1}{\pi-1}\right)}=\left|\,\frac{\pi^k-1}{\pi-1}\,\right|^2\implies x=\left|\,\frac{\pi^k-1}{\pi-1}\,\right|=|\pi^{k-1}+\pi^{k-2}+\ldots+\pi+1|$$

But since

$$1+\pi+\pi^2+\ldots+\pi^{p-1}=0\implies x=-|\pi^k+\pi^{k+1}+\ldots+\pi^{p-1}|$$

Finally :

$$\pi^k+\ldots+\pi^{p-1}=(\pi^k-1)+(\pi^{k+1}-1)+\ldots+(\pi^{p-1}-1)-(p-k-1)$$

and for $\,k\le j\le p-1\,$ :

$$\pi^j-1=(\pi-1)(\pi^{j-1}+\ldots+\pi+1)$$